# Stacked column using c3.js with external data

Tags: javascript, c3.js, stacked-chart

I plotted an analysis of complaints on a stacked column chart.

I managed to get my graph working using c3.js and the external data.
[See the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddYsX.png)

However, the code is gets only 3 issues from the external data. The data comes from an open platform. [Check out how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ11h.png)

I used javascript.

Here is the code. The snippet shows how I got converted the data and made it work on c3.js.

`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.getJSON('http://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/4ceee74d7dce4445b5c6582722b8c523_0/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=ISSUE,PERCENTAGE,YEAR&outSR=4326&f=json', function(complaint_data){

        var open_data  = complaint_data.features;
        var i, j, k;


        var dataset = [];
        var dataset2 = [];
        var dataset3 = [];
        var dataset_final = [];
        var modified_data = [];

        var mini_data = [];
        var mini_data2 = [];
        var mini_data3 = [];

        // Get all non-zero percentages
        for(i=0,k=0; i<open_data.length; ++i,++k){

            v = parseFloat(open_data[i]['attributes']['PERCENTAGE'].split('%'));

            if(v > 0){
                modified_data[k] = open_data[i];
            }else{
                --k;
            }


        }

        //console.log(modified_data)
        full_data = []
        some_d = [];

        for(j=0; j<modified_data.length; ++j){


            pvalue = parseFloat(modified_data[j]['attributes']['PERCENTAGE'].split('%'));


            if(modified_data[j]['attributes']['ISSUE']=="Abuse Of Power"){

                mini_data.push(pvalue)

                dataset[modified_data[j]['attributes']['ISSUE']] = {

                    data:mini_data
                }

            }else if(modified_data[j]['attributes']['ISSUE']=="Delay"){

                mini_data2.push(pvalue)

                dataset2[modified_data[j]['attributes']['ISSUE']] = {

                    data:mini_data2
                }
            }else if(modified_data[j]['attributes']['ISSUE']=="Inefficiency"){

                mini_data3.push(pvalue)

                dataset3[modified_data[j]['attributes']['ISSUE']] = {

                    data:mini_data3
                }
            }


        }

        dataset_final2 = ['Abuse_Of_Power']
        dataset_final3 = ['Delay']
        dataset_final4 = ['Inefficiency']

        for(q=0;q<dataset['Abuse Of Power']['data'].length; q++){
            dataset_final2.push(dataset['Abuse Of Power']['data'][q])
            dataset_final3.push(dataset2['Delay']['data'][q])
            dataset_final4.push(dataset3['Inefficiency']['data'][q])
        }



       // console.log(full_data)

        var chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#c3_container',
            title:{
                text: 'Analysis Of Complaints Received By Service Issues, Abuse of Power, Delay, Inefficiency 2012-2015'
            },
            data: {
                columns: [
                    dataset_final2,
                    dataset_final3,
                    dataset_final4
                ],
                type: 'bar',
                groups: [
                    ['Abuse_Of_Power', 'Delay', 'Inefficiency']
                ],
            },

            grid: {
                y: {
                   show:true
                }
            },
            axis: {
                x: {
                    type: 'category',
                    categories: ['by 31-Dec-2012','by 31-Dec-2013', 'by 31-Dec-2014', 'by 31-Dec-2015'],
                    label: 'Year'
                },
                y: {
                    label: 'Percentage %',
                    tick: {
                        format: function (d) { return d+"%"; }
                    }

                }
            }
        });


     })
      });
```

`

My question is how can I get all the issues/complaints into the graph without going through if else statements. I think there is a more efficient way of plotting the stacked chart considering how the data comes from the open platform. I do not know how to go about using javascript. Any ideas to point me in good direction?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to go with if else then you have to create json from server side and then you have to render it directly. 
So in c3.js there is always first value will be data name i.e

```
{ "obj":{
['data1',12,33,34,43],
['data2',22,44,55,66]
```

}
}

This is just rough idea. but you can go with this direction. 
Hope this will help.